# Angular scope issue with nested HTML elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have this very simple example where I am trying show a processing icon, clicking on the save button sets a `saving` flag in `$scope` in the controller.

My issue is that the button is disabled via the directive `ng-disabled` but the other directives under the button don't hold the value for `saving`

```
button.btn.btn-default(ng-show='editMode', ng-disabled='saving', ng-click='save()')
  ui-icon(ng-hide='saving', icon='fa-save')
  ui-icon-processing(ng-show='saving')
  span Save
```

What could cause this issue to happen?

Comment: can u show us the code ?

Comment: If that's all there is to it, I can't see a problem.
Can you upload the compiled code?
Here is a plunker of similar code that works fine.
http://plnkr.co/edit/BCT0JVPmQcxZ1C10Wwzp?p=preview

Comment: yes, I think the code is correct, I was wondering what would cause it this issue

Comment: I think I might have solved it.. removing the bootstrap classes fixes it in a `.btn.btn-default`  - really weird

Comment: It's tough to know exactly what is happening without a working application provided, but here's a guess. Is ui-icon a directive? Perhaps with an isolate scope? That would make the contents of the outer scope (including the "saving" flag) invisible inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the bootstrap classes fixed the issue. `btn.btn-default`

also had to remove some bootstrap button initialisation

```
$('.btn').button();
```